# Product of greatest integer functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show that if $x >0$ and $y > 0$ and $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$, then $[x][y] \leq [xy]$.

This is my work so far:

Assume that $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$ and $x,y >0$.  Now suppose that $[x]=m$ and $[y]=n$, where $m,n \in \Bbb {Z}$.  So then, $m \leq x < m+1$ and $n \leq y < n+1$.  So then, by multiplying the inequalities, we have $mn \leq xy < (m+1)(n+1) \implies mn \leq xy < mn+m+n+2$.  This means that the greatest integer less than or equal to xy is mn which equals $[x][y]$, and so therefore $[x][y] \leq [xy]$.

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track here, or how I can fix my errors?

Comment: you seem to be assuming that the difference between $(m+1)(n+1)$ and $mn$ is equal to $1$ (cause you claim that $mn$ is the greatest integer less than or equal $xy$). This is not true in general.

Comment: To elaborate on @Thomas' comment: take $x=y=1.5$.  Then $m=n=1$, but $[xy]=[2.25]=2$.

Comment: What do you need to prove to show that $k\le[xy]$? You essentially did it, you just did not notice, because you put some other irrelevant stuff in too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In$\let\leq\leqslant$ fact the inequality follows from the definition of $[\;]$. We have $[x]\leq x$ and $[y]\leq y$, hence $[x][y]\leq xy$.
$[x][y]$ is an integer which is $\leq xy$.
*By definition*, $[xy]$ is the largest integer $\leq xy$.
Any other integer $n$ satisfying $n\leq xy$ is at most $[xy]$.
In particular, $[x][y]\leq[xy]$.